# Is it possible to get the files changed information from commit ids using mercurial python library?

Tags: mercurial, buildbot, mercurial-hook, rhodecode

I am implementing a custom hook in Rhodecode CI, which sends a build request to Buildbot on every push. The hook gives me the revisions commit-id, how can I extract information about the files that were changed as part of this commit.

```
@has_kwargs({
'commit_ids': 'list of pushed commit_ids (sha1)',})
def _push_hook(*args, **kwargs):
     import mercurial # can I used this library to get this info?
     some_function(commit_id) # should return files changed
```

Can I use `mercurial` library or is there any other way to get this information programatically, using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With rhodecode:

```
from rhodecode.model.db import Repository
from rhodecode.api.utils import build_commit_data, Optional


class Commit:

    def __init__(self, repo_name, commit_id):
        self._commit_id = commit_id
        repo = Repository.get_by_repo_name(repo_name)
        self.vcs_repo = repo.scm_instance(cache=False)

    def files_changed(self):
        changeset_details = self._changeset_details(self._commit_id)
        files_changed_ = [diff.get("filename") for diff in changeset_details["diff"]]
        return files_changed_

    def _changeset_details(self, commit_id):
        pre_load = ['author', 'branch', 'date', 'message', 'parents',
                    'status', '_commit', '_file_paths']
        changes_details = Optional.extract("full")
        changeset = self.vcs_repo.get_changeset(commit_id, pre_load=pre_load)
        changeset_data = changeset.__json__()
        changeset_data['diff'] = build_commit_data(changeset, changes_details)
        return changeset_data
```

With HG:

```
from mercurial import ui, hg
hg_repo = hg.repository(ui.ui(), repo_path)
node = hg_repo.changelog.node(revision)    
log = hg_repo.changelog.read(node)
manifest, user, (time, timezone), files_changed, desc, extra = log
```